# How to get SpeedLimit in HERE API

Tags: here-api

I'm developing a web app where I need to know speed limit of specific road.
The call to API looks lie this:

```
$.get('http://cre.api.here.com/2/calculateroute.json',    
        'waypoint0=41.69758,-87.78397&waypoint1=41.70056,-87.77429&mode=fastest;car;&overlays=OVERLAYEXAMPLE1&storage=readonly&linkAttributes=speedLimit&app_id=XXX&app_code=YYY',
            function(data) {
                console.log(data.response);
            }
        );
```

The response I'm receiving does not contain "speedLimit" even when I'm explicitly requesting.

I found in documentation where it says:
https://developer.here.com/documentation/geocoder/topics/resource-type-response-geocode.html#resource-type-response-geocode__link-info

> Note: All link info attributes are subject to additional licensing. We reserve the right to require authorization on API level for all or individual attributes with future releases. Currently, only the SpeedLimit attribute requires authorization and the attribute is not included in LinkInfo if the client application is not authorized to receive this information.

Client says the app is authorized, so no issues should be with it.. but anyways I'm not receiving desired result-set which contains speed limit..

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You could show response which you get for your request. It might be valuable info to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use legattributes=li to get speedLimit attribute of a link.

Below is an example on how to get speedlimit for links(roads).

```
https://route.cit.api.here.com/routing/7.2/calculateroute.json?jsonAttributes=1&waypoint0=51.31854,9.51183&waypoint1=50.11208,8.68342&departure=2019-01-18T10:33:00&routeattributes=sh,lg&legattributes=li&linkattributes=nl,fc&mode=fastest;car;traffic:enabled&app_code=xxx&app_id=xxxx
```

Comment: I used this api but I am getting Permission Error.
This is not a valid app_id and app_code pair. Please verify that the values are not swapped between the app_id and app_code and the values provisioned by HERE (either by your customer representative or via http://developer.here.com/myapps) were copied correctly into the request.