# Drawing multiple polyline with different color using HERE API

Tags: here-api

I want to draw polyline on roads and based on specific road speedLimit show the polyline in different color, something like this:

[image: https://www.screencast.com/t/SQrjoc78P0uN]

Is it possible to achieve this whit HERE map API?

```
var lineString = new H.geo.LineString();

        routeShape.forEach(function(point) {
            var parts = point[0].split(',');

            lineString.pushLatLngAlt(parts[0], parts[1]);

        });

        polyline = new H.map.Polyline(lineString, {
            style: {
                lineWidth: 4,
                strokeColor: 'rgba(0, 128, 255, 0.7)'
            }
        });

        map.addObject(polyline);
        map.setViewBounds(polyline.getBounds(), true);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use  routeattributes: "shape" for your routing request, and you may get each segment and associated speed limit as below:

```
       let route = res.body.response.route[0];
        let legs = route.leg;
        let links = [];
        legs.forEach(leg => {
            Object.assign(links, leg.link);
        });
        console.log("#links", links.length);

        links.forEach(link => {
            let sl = link.speedLimit; // in m/sec
            let shape = link.shape; // shape to draw

            let style = {
                lineWidth: 4,
                strokeColor: "yellow"
            };
            if (sl < 50 * 1000 / 3600)
                style.strokeColor = "red";
            else if (sl < 90 * 1000 / 3600)
                style.strokeColor = "orange";
            else
                style.strokeColor = "green";

            let line = new H.geo.LineString();
            shape.forEach(latlng => {
                let coord = latlng.split(",");
                line.pushLatLngAlt(coord[0], coord[1]);
            });

            let polyline = new H.map.Polyline(line, {
                style: style
            });

            /* group created previously as
               group = new H.map.Group();
               map.addObject(group);
            */
            group.addObject(polyline);

        });
```

just draw each shape independantly, according to your own style depending on speed limit.
[image]

Comment: thanks @DevBab, how can I style each shape independently, currently I can style only the Polyline which contains the shapes array. I could not see the way to style each shape independently in documentation..

Comment: With above code, you get the geometry (shape) of each link. you have to create a polyline for each shape, and use a style which represent the specific speed limit.

Answer (score 1):

Your question poses two kind of interpretations. I shall try answering both so that you can pick your intend. Hope it helps!

1. How to draw a route with different color segments - 
   H.geo.LineString is used to achieve this. Refer https://developer.here.com/documentation/maps/topics_api/h-geo-linestring.html#h-geo-linestring. You can also read this article(https://developer.here.com/blog/who-wants-ice-cream-a-here-maps-api-for-javascript-tutorial-part-4-advanced-routing) where they try to achieve the same using H.geo.Strip (which has been deprecated and replaced by H.geo.LineString).
2. How to get speed limits of each link in a route - 
   Using routing api as given in the below example. Check the answer in [How to get SpeedLimit in HERE API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54240906/how-to-get-speedlimit-in-here-api)

   https://route.cit.api.here.com/routing/7.2/calculateroute.json?jsonAttributes=1&waypoint0=51.31854,9.51183&waypoint1=50.11208,8.68342&departure=2019-01-18T10:33:00&routeattributes=sh,lg&legattributes=li&linkattributes=nl,fc&mode=fastest;car;traffic:enabled&app_code=xxx&app_id=xxx

Comment: We can use `H.geo.LineString` or `H.geo.Strip` to collect parts as in this example:
`
var lineString = new H.geo.LineString();

routeShape.forEach(function(point) {
    var parts = point[0].split(',');

    lineString.pushLatLngAlt(parts[0], parts[1]);

});
`
but when we pass lineString to `H.geo.Polyline` there are only one style can be applied:
`
polyline = new H.map.Polyline(lineString,  {
                style:
                    {
                        lineWidth: 4,
                        strokeColor: 'red'
                    }
            });
`